# URL in a iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I need to change an URL in iframe in this mode.

Default is:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2Fimages%2Fcataloghi%2Ffile.pdf" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
```

But when I'm on desktop iframe src must become:

`<iframe src="images/cataloghi/file.pdf" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>`

In this way, on desktops with modern browsers the PDF is read by the browser reader, on smartphones and tablets it uses Google Docs Viewer.

Unfortunately, Google Docs, especially on desktop, often does not load its viewer and so I would be able to partially solve the problem.

‎Surely I will need an ID on the frame, for this I used this code:‎

:

```
<script>$(function(){ $('iframe').attr('id','something'); }); </script>
```

And work fine because in the page there's not another iframe.

Thanks

Comment: In all modern browser PDF viewers is active.
If I have to download the PDF directly, obviously I don't solve the problem of viewing the PDF inside the site instead, also for obvious branding reasons.
So since the problem I exposed I see is a common problem, I was looking for a workaround that would fix everything.
Unfortunately, the PDF reader in smartphones does not work if you are using a viewer within a site.
If I had to find a solution for the downloads, I would not have opened the question.

Comment: Ok, but this not resolve my problem when I need to view PDF in my website. We can sit here and debate as long as we want, but the problem is not solved. I have to view that PDF within the site and not externally, and I have to do it with the existing tools for a small website.
So, the solution and workaround that would solve the problem for me is what I have set out.

Unless someone has a solution that allows you to view the PDF on any device without holes, unfortunately whatever you use from time to time does not load the viewer. And this problem is global.